# How to get MIN() MAX() values from cassandra in java bean?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1, spring-data-cassandra

I can get aggregate function value of count in setter and getter in java bean by mentioning column name count.
for example, select count(*) from employee; i can get output in getCount();
may i know how can i get this same for MIN(total_marks) / MAX (total_marks) in java?
i have used same getter and setter technique mentioning getMin and getMax , but it returns 0. 
Can anyone solve my issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra Query Language doesn't support such things. You should use some query engine like Hive or Spark SQL to perform them.

Comment: Yup, found it before i have posting this question here itself. Expected any other options other than query engines. Thats it...